# How to set dynamic UICollectionView cell height?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

How to set dynamic cell height?

I need set cell size in this method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

I try do this:

```
cell.bounds = CGRect(x: cell.bounds.origin.x, y: cell.bounds.origin.y, width: width, height: height)
```

but then I can't scrool down...

and I try this methiod:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

but this method is ben call first, then call this method:

```
cell.bounds = CGRect(x: cell.bounds.origin.x, y: cell.bounds.origin.y, width: width, height: height)
```

so.. how to change cell height?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set it up as per normal. (normal constraints [left,right,top,bottom, and height] and IBOutlet for the UICollectionView.

Secondly, make IBOutlets for the height constraint, top constraint, and bottom constraint.

Thirdly, add ->

```
//these are the outlets I am naming generic names but name them what you wish

 IBOutlet var collectionViewCellDynamicConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
 IBOutlet var topConstraintDynamicConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
 IBOutlet var bottomConstraintDynamicConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

 //into viewDidLoad

 collectionViewCell.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentHeight",      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

  topConstraintDynamicConstraint.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentTop", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

  bottomConstraintDynamicConstraint.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentBottom", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

 //create this override func

 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {



 //try use this segment below as well but if it doesn't work then remove it and try run again

 self.collectionViewCell.sizeThatFits()

 //



 self.collectionViewCellDynamicConstraint.constant = collectionViewCell.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.collectionViewCell.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max)).height

 // set these values (below) to the space/value that you set them at normally. Often what is needed is a refresh after changing the height of the view/collectionViewCell

    self.topSpaceOld.constant = 0.4 

    self.bottomSpaceOld.constant = 10


}




 // you need to de-initialise them before you leave the view or else it will crash
deinit {
    self.collectionViewCell.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentHeight")

    self.topConstraintDynamicConstraint.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentTop"

    self.bottomConstraintDynamicConstraint.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentBottom")
 )



}
```

there might be some naming issues but it should work. This code worked for getting a UITextView to work inside of a scroll view for dynamic height of the view. It should be the same concept.

Comment: Hi, did this answer help you at all? If it worked, please verify that it was a correct answer

Answer (score -2):

You can resize your cell with the sizeForItemAtIndexPath delegate method when used as below. You need to return a CGSize for the cell. Can you show us the full code of your implementation of this method?

Working example;

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```